# TYPO3 Frontend Editing not working in TYPO3 8.7

Tags: typo3, frontend, typo3-8.7.x

I am using the system extension feedit to provide frontend editing in a TYPO3 website. In TYPO3 7.6 this worked correctly.

With the same website and unchanged configuration in TYPO3 8.7 however, the edit icons are not showing up. They are part of the HTML sourcecode of the page, but they are hidden with inline CSS: `style="display: none;"`.

Thinking that some part of my frontend might interfere with TYPO3 here, I have already tried removing all of my custom JavaScript and most of my CSS, but it doesn't change a thing: The edit icons are not shown.

Can someone enlighten me how to get them to show up again?

Answer (score 0):

The old (unmaintained) frontend editing feature has been removed from the TYPO3 core in TYPO 8.
You should switch to https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/frontend_editing/
Read here for more details:
https://typo3.org/article/the-new-frontend-editing-for-typo3/

Comment: The new frontend editing won't make it into 9.5. It's just not ready to be part of the core. For the time being it'll stay in the TER and can be installed as any other extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why they did it with inline CSS instead of removing them totally if they are dead. 
But you can easy activate them by adding CSS to your Website.

```
.typo3-editPanel{display:block !important;overflow:hidden;clear:both}
.typo3-editPanel .typo3-editPanel-btn-group{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;float:left;padding:3px 0 3px 3px;background:#f5f5f5;border:1px solid #c5c5c5}
.typo3-editPanel .typo3-editPanel-btn-group .typo3-editPanel-btn{display:block !important;width:auto;height:24px;margin-right:3px;background:#f5f5f5;border:1px solid #c5c5c5;padding:3px}
.typo3-editPanel .typo3-editPanel-btn-group .typo3-editPanel-btn:hover{background:#dcdcdc;border:1px solid #acacac}
.typo3-editPanel .typo3-editPanel-btn-group .typo3-editPanel-btn svg{height:100%;width:auto}
.typo3-editPanel .typo3-editPanel-label{display:none}
```

This CSS shouldn't interfere with your normal Website. I don't know if they work in 8.7, but in 9.x they are also deactivated and bringing them back with CSS works fine.